# How to convert an image to vector / bezier path in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibezierpath

I have an image in black & white, just outlines. I want to convert that image to bezier paths. 
*( I have to convert the do it side application)*

**Sample Image** [image]

Comment: try http://www.paintcodeapp.com

Comment: @GoGreen I have to do it in side iOS application using objective c or swift code.

Comment: how are you getting this image? if you already have svg or psd files you can upload it to paintcode which will convert it to objectivec or swift code. Or you can draw the image in the paintcode app and then convert it to code. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Are you planning to trace it manually or you want some kind of algorithm to do the tracing for you?

Comment: @jane I am looking for algorithm.

Comment: did you find any solution?